# Create trigger in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I created a trigger in SQL but I got an error and do not know what is the fault in my code. I tried to find out my solution from others questions but did not find any answer according to my problem

I need a trigger that changes the value of my tables variable for example: I have a value (200kg) in a variable named `used_weight` and when I insert or update or delete on this variable the value should be drives like my code.

And the compilation error is below

> Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors

When I update my variable the error I got is

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-04098: trigger 'ALI.LEFT_BALANCE' is invalid and failed re-validation

This is my code:

```
create or replace trigger left_balance
before delete or insert or update on reels_table
for each row
declare
begin
    user_weight:=:new.used_weight+:old.used_weight;
    left_weight:=weight-used_weight;
end;
/
```

and i declared the variables but error remains same

```
create or replace trigger left_balance
before delete or insert or update on reels_table
for each row
declare
x number=:new.user_weight;
xx number=:old.user_weight;

begin
user_weight:=x+xx;
left_weight:=weight-user_weight;
end;
/
```

Comment: If it's insert you won't have an old.user_weight, same if it's a delete there is no new.user_weight. You have to use condition for each action.

Comment: You didn't declare `user_weight`, `left_weight`, `weight` nor `used_weight`. You're probably missing some `:new.` or `:old.` there.

Comment: @sticky bit Is it necessary to declare these variables while working on table name.

Comment: Yes, if you want them as variables. But I do suspect you want to access the column with the respective name from `:new` or `:old`. But then you also need to write `:new.` or `:old.` before them.

Comment: You've tagged this `[oracleforms]` but the code you're showing is a **database** trigger. Perhaps you need to clarify your question with some details about the application which is supposed to implement this rule.

Comment: @sticky bit i declared the variables as you can see above edited question but remains same problem

Comment: No I cannot see you declare the variables. A declaration goes `<variable name> <variable type>;` e.g. `myvariable number;`. And `number=:new.user_weight` is no type (unless you created one with such an obscure name). Still I believe you want to add the missing `:new.` or `:old.` prefixes. But well, what can I do other than say it trice?

Comment: What tool are you using to develop in PL/SQL? Whatever it is, you really need to find out how it displays compilation errors, because asking "what could be wrong?" on Stack Overflow for every single error is not an efficient development workflow. There is a view named `user_errors`, SQL\*Plus has a `show errors` command, tools such as SQL Developer, PL/SQL Developer and TOAD highlight them automatically etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below is a simple example but first let me explain several things:

in plsql code, when you want to use variables you have to declare them (as  @sticky bit explained ).

example :

```
 declare var1 varchar2(10); 
 var1 varchar2(10);
```

You are using the trigger on the table reels_table1 , this will lead to mutating error, however because you used `before` you didnt face the error.

as @Daniel E point out the insert will not have old value.

Note in the below example I created a test table and I added a condition in the update maybe you forget it.

```
drop table reels_table1
/
create table reels_table1 (id number(4), user_weight number(4), left_weight number(4),weight number(4) )
/
create or replace trigger left_balance
before delete or insert or update on reels_table1
for each row
declare

x number(2)  := :new.user_weight;
xx number (2) := :old.user_weight;
begin

update reels_table1 set 
user_weight =x+xx where id =1;

update reels_table1 set left_weight = weight - user_weight where id=1;

end;
/
```